# Storing an array of constructors/classes

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Let's say that I have the following interface:

```
interface ISomeFeature
{
  execute(): Promise<void>;
}
```

I now want to be able to map different features using keywords.

Something like:

```
config.map<CustomFeature>("theKey");
```

So that I can later retrieve it and create a new instance:

```
var type = config.get("theKey");
var instance = new type();
```

I know how to do that in C#, but is it possible in typescript? I don't understand what I should do in the map method nor what the actual `Map<,>` should look like.

I've tinkered around with something like:

```
myMap: Map<string, ???> = new Map();

map<TFeature extends ISomeFeature>(key: string) {
   this.myMap.set(key, ????);
}

get(key: string): ISomeFeature {
  return new this.myMap.get(key)();
}
```

But as I said. I don't know what to store in the map.

Comment: Do you have a known set of string-named generics (like all the HTMLElements)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your interface has this shape and your features look this then,

```
interface Feature {
  execute(): void;
}
class Feature1 implements Feature {
  execute() {
    console.log("From feature 1")
  }
}
class Feature2 implements Feature {
  execute() {
    console.log("From feature 2")
  }
}
```

You can use `{ new(): Feature }` type in your record.

```
class Features {
  private map: Record<string, { new(): Feature }> = {}

  setFeature(key: string, cls: { new(): Feature }) {
    this.map[key] = cls
  }

  getFeature(key: string): Feature {
    return new this.map[key]()
  }
}
```

Then, you can do this

```
const features = new Features()

features.setFeature("feature1", Feature1);
features.setFeature("feature2", Feature2);

const feature1 = features.getFeature("feature1");
const feature2 = features.getFeature("feature2");

feature1.execute();
feature2.execute();
```